# Why can't C++ locals captured by reference be accessed through the stack pointer?

Tags: c++

I noticed that compilers implement capture by reference by making an array on the stack of pointers to the captured locals, which can be passed to the lambda to access them. That surprised me because the compiler knows where the locals are relative to the stack pointer, so I thought it could just pass the stack pointer. That would make one less indirection in the lambda and save the work of putting the pointers on the stack. I was wondering why the compiler can't do that?

For example, this C++:

```
#include <functional>
extern void test(std::function<void()>& f);
int test2(int x, int y)
{
    std::function<void()> f([&]() { x += y; });
    test(f);
    return x;
}
```

generates this assembly on Clang 13 -O3 (comments mine):

```
mov     dword ptr [rsp + 8], edi    // put x on the stack
mov     dword ptr [rsp + 12], esi   // put y on the stack
lea     rax, [rsp + 8]
mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], rax   // put &x on the stack
lea     rax, [rsp + 12]
mov     qword ptr [rsp + 24], rax   // put &y on the stack
mov     qword ptr [rsp + 40], offset std::_Function_handler<void (), test2(int, int)::$_0>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&)
mov     qword ptr [rsp + 32], offset std::_Function_handler<void (), test2(int, int)::$_0>::_M_manager(std::_Any_data&, std::_Any_data const&, std::_Manager_operation)
lea     rdi, [rsp + 16]
call    test(std::function<void ()>&)
```

and similar on GCC and MSVC.

Comment: A lambda is an object (of an anonymous class), and captures are stored by having them as (private and non-static) member variables of that object. This might be what happens here, the lambda object is stored on the stack, and then the member variables are initialized.

Comment: `std::function` is not a lambda, and is rather complex and hard to optimize. The compiler will prob get rid of all that code if you actually use just a lambda.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The standard very clearly [does not specify](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-12) how reference-captured variables are represented in the closure object. Why do compilers not just put the stack pointer into the closure type?

Comment: I wonder if you'll increase your chances of getting a useful response by using tags for compilers of interest (g++, etc).   Your question ultimately comes down to "why don't these compilers do it this way rather than that?" which isn't really in scope for the c++ tag.

Comment: I believe your question can be answered by rephrasing it as "why don't compiler implementers have the time to implement optimizations for every imaginable special case?"

Comment: @j6t Misread a little. Capture by values are stored as copies, but like the spec says it's unspecified for references.

Comment: I don't think that std::function is the problem, because I get the same result if I cast the lambda to void* and pass it that way. I did assume there was a reason the compilers can't do this, so perhaps the answer is that they could but just don't. Still, I'm a little curious! It feels like using the stack pointer would be easier than adding the extra indirection, so I suspect there's something I don't grasp here. Thanks everyone for responding.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is not the non optimized lambda, but all the stuff around `std::function`.

If you simplify your code to:

```
template < typename F>
void test(F& f )
{
    f();
}

int test2(int x, int y)
{
    auto f=[&]() { x += y; };
    test(f);
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    return test2(1,2);
}
```

The assembly becomes

```
test2(int, int):
        lea     eax, [rdi+rsi]
        ret
main:
        mov     eax, 3
        ret
```

Which is fully optimized out all the stuff and propagate the result as constant.

The the difference: [without std::function](https://godbolt.org/z/a6MTPs5qE) vs [with std::function](https://godbolt.org/z/dz9b7h5sh)

Comment: This misses the point: The question was not "why don't compilers optimize away all the stuff", but "in the cases where compilers cannot optimize away all the stuff, why can they not still optimize by-reference captures of local variables into a single pointer".

Answer (score 0):

1. Here is [godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qoPc996sd) (extended a bit).
2. I've added `testABI` to show that parameters to you function are passed by registry.

```cpp
useTestABI():                        # @useTestABI()
        mov     edi, 3
        mov     esi, 5
        jmp     testABI(int, int)                    # TAILCALL
```

3. So in `test2` starts by creating `x` and `y` to create locals on stack so it would be possible to pass them by reference.
4. After that lambda is created on stack, so addresses of `x` and `y` are saved to stack. Also addresses of functions to be invoked when lambda is used (polymorphism without vtable) are added to labda on stack

Now you do not know what `test` will do with `f`. It can clone `f` so in such case `f` have to be copied from stack to other place. Also on other side when `test` is compiled compiler do not know what kind of lambda was passed. Creating copy may have side effect or not. So creating a copy must be possible and must be compatible with predefined ABI.

So this shortcut you are describing is possible only when compiler could known content of `test`. When content of `test` is not know `f` must be fully created to make it possible to clone it when needed.

Comment: "this shortcut... is possible only when compiler could known content of `test`." I disagree. `function` type-erases the closure type anyway; what `test` does with it is irrelevant. The question remains: why can the compiler not represent both references with a single pointer?

Comment: Yeah, I wonder what `test` could do that would prevent using the stack pointer. If it clones the lambda, wouldn't the copy refer to the same captured locals, and so be able to access them through the same pointer?